# CSS rainbow gradient loop animation

Tags: css, colors, linear-gradients

Is trying to find a way to create CSS rainbow stripe animation loop... something similar to this:

[image: rainbow color loop]

Currently only able to create an image of the rainbow stripe but now sure how to create an animation that is continuous just like in the gif with CSS.

```
background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,154,0,1) 10%, rgba(208,222,33,1) 20%, rgba(79,220,74,1) 30%, rgba(63,218,216,1) 40%, rgba(47,201,226,1) 50%, rgba(28,127,238,1) 60%, rgba(95,21,242,1) 70%, rgba(186,12,248,1) 80%, rgba(251,7,217,1) 90%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%);
```

The image:
[image]

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Look at the example by Manuel Pinto https://1stwebdesigner.com/15-css-background-effects/

Answer (score 6):

You can try like below:

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,154,0,1) 10%, rgba(208,222,33,1) 20%, rgba(79,220,74,1) 30%, rgba(63,218,216,1) 40%, rgba(47,201,226,1) 50%, rgba(28,127,238,1) 60%, rgba(95,21,242,1) 70%, rgba(186,12,248,1) 80%, rgba(251,7,217,1) 90%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%) 
   0 0/100% 200%;
   animation: a 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes a {
  to {background-position:0 -200%}
}
```

Comment: For those who need the rainbow in `horizontal` way just use `to right,` as first parameter of `linear-gradient()`, ie. `linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, ...)`

Comment: @ino that's not enough, we only need to update the position to -200% 0 and the size to 200% 100%